# backbone/underscore template in mustache format causing error on # pound/hash symbol?

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, underscore.js, mustache

I'm using backbone's underscore templating engine with the mustache formatting patterns.

I have already been successfully using it elsewhere in the project but now for the first time I'm using the looping list patterns from mustache to populate the template which is throwing an error which I'm a bit baffled by.
The error in chrome is:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"
```

and points to underscore's template function in the backtrace, which is pretty useless but in firebug i get a more helpful error like this:

[image]

Suggesting that the hash symbol '#' is the issue, which would make sense as I know that mustache is working ok as there are many other parts of the project using it well, also this is the first time I'm using the hash sybol in my templates.It looks like a problem either with the looping feature or with the interpolation/template settings for underscore.

Here's the relevant piece of my template:

```
<div class="thumblist thumblistleft" id="currentprojectslist">
    <div class="thumb-list-header">
         <h2>current projects</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-list-area">
        <ol>
        {{#worklist}}       <!----- LOOK HERE --->
            {{#current}}
              <li><a>{{title}}</a></li>
            {{/current}}
        {{/worklist}}
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's a sample of the JSON (which all validates fine)

```
{blah blah blah lot in here before,"worklist":[{"thumb":"img/project-s.jpg","id":"340","title":"Test Project One","desc":"big load of content here","current":true}], and so on....}
```

I was initially following this example here for reference:
http://mustache.github.com/#demo

**NOW HERES WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM MIGHT BE:**

underscore.js suggests using this before rendering a mustache template:

```
_.templateSettings = {
     evaluate : /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
     interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

also:

```
interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
```

Also just the interpolate statement, ive tried both. However my regex knowledge is really poor and I have a feeling it might not accomodate the hash? At any rate.... I'm totally stumped.
Can someone help me out here?

is it even possible to loop like this? looking at underscore source i'm not sure:
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-120

Thanks very much

Comment: The pattern `/\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g` will match `{{#foo}}` and capture `#foo`. You could avoid capturing the hash by using `/\{\{#?([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g`, altho I think it will cause other problems.

Comment: did you ever manage to loop like this? I would really like to, it's very annoying in underscore to write out a simple if across multiple evaluate lines to check if a flag is present in my JSON.

Comment: hey, sadly underscore won't do it natively, you have to include mustache.js and do mustache.render, as below.. It's really annoying i agree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm posting for the sakes of anyone else facing this issue.
After a lot of googling to no avail, i went through the underscore.js source with a fine toothed comb and basically you have to either use underscore's template syntax, writein ugly function processors into your JSON or include mustache.js into your source and call:

```
Mustache.render(mytemplate,mymodel)
```

and foresake underscore's

```
_.template(..) function
```

Annoying but whatever, I hope that helps someone

Answer (score 22):

Came up against this problem today. The issue seems to be the order that Underscore does the templating: escape, interpolate, then evaluate. So you need to explicitly ignore any matches for `{{#` in your interpolation regex:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  evaluate:    /\{\{#([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g,            // {{# console.log("blah") }}
  interpolate: /\{\{[^#\{]([\s\S]+?)[^\}]\}\}/g,  // {{ title }}
  escape:      /\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,         // {{{ title }}}
}
```

It doesn't actually work the same way as Mustache: there aren't proper blocks in Underscore's templating, so there is no need for a closing block `{{/}}`. You just need to match your statements up like you would with standard Underscore templates.

Comment: Note that with the above syntax you should make sure that there is a space between your expression and the `{{ }}`. Example: `{{ test }}` will work, `{{test}}` will not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using the # symbol but I experienced a similar error once I tried to use the triple mustache `{{{name}}}` for unescaped values with the setting:

```
interpolate : /\{\{\{(.+?)\}\}\}/g,
escape : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
```

If that's the reason you came here, the following setting works

```
interpolate : /\{\{\{(\s*\w+?\s*)\}\}\}/g,
escape : /\{\{(\s*\w+?\s*)\}\}(?!\})/g,
```

I tried Max's format but that didn't work for me because I have a mix of double and triple mustache expressions and while the triple expression worked fine it was stripping a character from each end of the variable name in the double mustache i.e. `{{title}}` led to underscore looking for a variable named `itl`

Comment: I came here for the original question, followed the answers and this regex was what worked for me, thank you!

Comment: If anyone comes across this: `{{title}}`  led to underscore looking for a variable named `itl`, which is actually what Niyaz pointed out below Max's question: Add spaces between expression and braces and it'll work. So instead of `{{title}}` you need to write `{{ title }}`.